# try catch skipping exception

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

```
try
{
    return strngarray.Select(strngarrayelem =>
    {
        string[] data = strngarrayelem .Split(',');

        return new xyzClass(data[1], data[2], data[0], (Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(data[3]), data.Length > 4 ? data[4] : "N/A");
    });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("abc");
    return Enumerable.Empty<xyzClass>();
}
```

I am getting format exception in

```
(Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(data[3])
```

I try catching it by try-catch but  exception is still thrown by app level try catch and not caught by my local try catch.
Why my try catch not getting error ?

Comment: Because `.Select` is evaluated in a lazy way.

Comment: What happens if you add `.ToList()` after the `Select`?

Comment: Is there really no way to detect you got nothing valid than to catch an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are just returning a LINQ query, it's not yet executed(like for example with `ToList`).

So if you want to catch the exception here you should consider materializing it to a collection in this method.  You could still return `IEnumerable<xyzClass>` since `List<xyzClass>` implements that interface.

```
try
{
    return strngarray.Select(strngarrayelem =>
    {
        string[] data = strngarrayelem .Split(',');

        return new xyzClass(data[1], data[2], data[0], (Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(data[3]), data.Length > 4 ? data[4] : "N/A");
    }).ToList(); // <------- HERE !!!
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("abc");
    return Enumerable.Empty<xyzClass>();
}
```

If you don't know which method is just returning a query, look at the documentation in MSDN for the keyword `deferred`. For example [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method is implemented by using **deferred** execution. The
>   immediate return value is an object that stores all the information
>   that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this
>   method **is not executed until the object is enumerated either by
>   calling its `GetEnumerator` method directly or by using 
>   `foreach`**

Methods like for example `Enumerable.ToList` or `ToArray` call `GetEnumerator`, so they will execute the query. MSDN:

> The `ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method **forces immediate
>   query evaluation** and returns a `List<T>` that contains the query
>   results. You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a
>   cached copy of the query results.
>
> `ToArray<TSource>` has similar behavior but returns an array instead of
>   a `List<T>`.

Comment: I hate to be nitpick-y, but I always point out to newcomers that they shouldn't use abbreviations like "f.e." because 1.) this isn't social media and 2.) there are tons of people on this site who struggle with English.

Comment: @rory.ap If wouldn't even have thought that "f.e." means "e.g.".

Comment: i must say it was quite educating

Comment: I don't think it's "a thing" in the way that "e.g." (Latin exemplī grātiā -- "free example") or "i.e." (Latin id est, -- "that is") are "things".  Those are well-established abbreviations.  It's more like when someone says "wrt" to mean "with respect to" or "b/c" to mean "because".